# Pausing CSS Slide with -webkit-animation-play-state:paused; not working

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, slide

I have the following code:

```
        .picTransition .item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: picTransition 56s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: picTransition 56s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: picTransition 56s linear infinite;
  animation: picTransition 56s linear infinite;
}

.picTransition.paused{
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state:paused;
    -o-animation-play-state:paused; 
    animation-play-state:paused;
}

.picTransition .item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 14s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 14s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 14s;
  animation-delay: 14s;
}
.picTransition .item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 28s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 28s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 28s;
  animation-delay: 28s;
}
.picTransition .item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 42s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 42s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 42s;
  animation-delay: 42s;
}
```

I am making a mistake on the how to pause the slides. I have used the animation-play-state: paused, but it does not work. I can use the jquery function, but I really want to try and get this to work in css only. Am I screwing up on the parent child relation? Or is this timing sequence not supported or messing with the pause issue? Perhaps I need to do a hover type pause and build a new div for that? I know I am making a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're saying any element with the classes `.picTransition` & `.paused` should pause the animation, but without JavaScript that will either be all of the time as you've set the class by default or never because it doesn't have that class.

If you'd like it to pause on an event use JavaScript to add/remove the class or if it's a simple hover event, change `.picTransition.paused` to `.picTransition:hover`.

If `.paused` is a child element of `.picTransition` make sure there's a space between the two in your selector.

If none of that is right, could you possibly create a jsFiddle for us to look at?